# How can I eliminate dead keys on Mac OS X with international keyboard?

Tags: macos

The keys ^¨~ ´` etc are dead keys on my swedish keyboard on Mac OS X (or half-dead since they start b typing the letter and then wait for the next character until the decision is made).

How can I turn this off to make them fully live?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele) is an editor for Mac OS X keyboard layouts. I haven't used it for eliminating dead keys but it knows about them and provides very detailed access to the layout. I'm optimistic that you can create a new keyboard layout (from an existing one) without dead keys. (I'm using myself an enhanced keyboard layout to have access to German umlauts on a US keyboard.) A keyboard layout goes into `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts` and can be activated in the International system preference pane.

As per information from [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele) site:

> A more flexible, cross-plaform keyboard utility for macOS 10.7 (Lion) and later is [Keyman](https://keyman.com). However, Keyman does not use the same .keylayout files as Ukelele and requires additional software to use.