# Special characters (^´`) do not invoke (keyPressed / keyReleased / keyTyped) method of TextField

Tags: java, javafx, handler, textfield, keylistener

I have a `javafx.scene.control.TextField` and implemented the `keyPressed()`, `keyReleased()`, and `keyTyped()` methods.

These methods will be invoked by all keys except for ^ ´ `.

The problem is that the `TextField` adds these characters but I can't handle the input of these characters.

I think it's because these characters are no "real" characters and they are normally used in combination with vocals (like é, ì, ô, ú). But even when I "complete" the character (e.g. if I press ^ and then o, then the `TextField`will show ô), the methods does not register the input.

Comment: Have you tried using an event filter instead of a handler? It may allow you to catch the event before the control consumes is.

Comment: hmm i have no problem catching the " ^ ´ `." keys here. Maybe i didn't understand something. In any case if the characters you want to catch is a combination of two or more keys have you tried to catch multiple keys for example to check if the shift + 6 is pressed etc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*How can I eliminate dead keys on Mac OS X with international keyboard?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/455799/230513)